# Laravel, return recordset where certain column is unique

Tags: laravel, orm, unique

I would like to return a recordset in laravel where a certain column should always be unique.

So for example

users:

```
 | id | type 
 1     basic
 2     pro
 3     pro
```

I want the recordset to only return:

```
      1     basic
      2     pro
```

Tried distinct and all the options from the documentation to no avail.
What is the right way to approach this issue?

Comment: Distinct won't work. `group by type` will work and will show the lowest id (if the id is an autoincrement)

Comment: Trouts could you please provide an example so i can accept answer? thank you. I believe I have tried group_by also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you need would look like this:

```
SELECT id,type FROM youtTable GROUP BY type
```

But keep in mind that the id you get is actually the value of the most recent entry! The hting ist that if you for any reason have table that looks like this:

```
 | id | type 
 1     basic
 3     pro
 2     pro
```

you might end up with a result like this:

```
  1     basic
  3     pro
```

So if you need the lowest id and are certain that the id does not correspond to the order the rows were put into the database you might be better of adding a order by like so:

```
SELECT id,type FROM youtTable GROUP BY type ORDER BY id
```